# FileTypeAssociation for WIndowsPhone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, manifest

I have the following settings in my Windows Phone 8.0 app manifest :

```
    <Extensions>
      <FileTypeAssociation Name="My application File Type" TaskID="_default" NavUriFragment="fileToken=%s">
        <SupportedFileTypes>
          <FileType>.myapp</FileType>
        </SupportedFileTypes>
      </FileTypeAssociation>
      <Protocol Name="abc" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
      <Protocol Name="abcs" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
    </Extensions>
```

I want similar auto launch of the application for .myapp type files in my Windows Phone 8.1 app. However, when I try the same code there it says TaskID and NavUriFragment are not supported. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Windows Phone 8.1 app I'm assuming that you mean a Universal App. In that case you are going to want to change the registration to a [FileType Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn423275.aspx).

```
    <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <FileTypeAssociation Name="test">
        <DisplayName>My App Type</DisplayName>
        <InfoTip>This was created by my app</InfoTip>
        <SupportedFileTypes>
          <FileType ContentType="x-application/myapp">.myapp</FileType>
        </SupportedFileTypes>
      </FileTypeAssociation>
    </Extension>
```